# Reading an Int from a Binary FIle

Tags: c++, wav, binary-data, ifstream, fread

I have been having a heck of a time reading in an int from a .Wav file. I've been following the .wav specifications listed [Here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/). I'm trying to read an int (Subchunk2Size) from the header and then the data into an array of shorts. I am running into obstacles with both fread() and ifstream.read(). I will list my problems with both reading technique problems, but really only need an answer to one.

**fread()**

```
    sprintf(filename, "C:\\Users\\MacbookWin7\\wavs\\%s.wav", word);
FILE * infile = fopen(filename, "rb");
if (infile != NULL)
{
    int f = ferror(infile);
    int d = fseek(infile, 40, SEEK_SET);
    int * subChunk2Size = new int[1];
    int i = fread(subChunk2Size, sizeof(int), 1, infile);
    int g = ferror(infile);
```

**The Problem**: fread does not read in anything, i is always initialized to 0.

I have tried many different combinations of declaring subChunk2Size, trying to declare a pointer, an array - both with single and multiple elements, declaring a nullptr, and declaring an int and passing in its reference.

**ifstream.read()**

```
    sprintf(filename, "C:\\Users\\MacbookWin7\\wavs\\%s.wav", word);
ifstream sampleStream(filename,ios::binary);
char * samplesStr;

if (sampleStream.is_open())
{
    sampleStream.seekg(40);
    char * subChunk2SizeStr = new char[4];
    sampleStream.read(subChunk2SizeStr, 4);
    int subChunk2Size = 0;
    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        subChunk2Size = (subChunk2Size << 8) + subChunk2SizeStr[i];
    }
    int numBytes = subChunk2Size + *nsamples * 2;
    char * samplesStr = new char[numBytes];
    sampleStream.read(samplesStr, numBytes);
    sampleStream.close();
    short * samples = new short[numBytes / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < numBytes / 2; i++)
    {
        int b = i * 2;
        samples[i] = samplesStr[b+1];
        samples[i] = (samples[i] << 8) + samplesStr[b];
    }
```

**The Problem**: My first reads and bit shifts turn out the correct answer of around 22,000, but I am unable to read in the shorts with the second loop.

*I would like to thank anybody for giving my problem some consideration.*

Comment: I don't know if any of these is causing your problem (you didn't state _what_ your problem is, actually): 1. shifting with signed values can yield undefined behavior; 2. `char` can be signed and would get sign extended when converted, causing more grief with shifting; 3. you don't seem to release the memory you allocated.

Comment: Are you on a PowerPC mac? If not, why are you messing about doing byte-ordering manipulations?

Comment: Dietmar, I don't know how to be any more clear with the problems, so I think we are just stuck. Thank you for your other tips.

Mats, I am just trying to read in the SubChunk2Size and wav data - I am trying every way possible to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

I took your code, mangled it a little bit, and it seems to show reasonable results when I'm using a 16-bit per sample, stereo input, such as [this](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/Samples/AFsp/M1F1-int16-AFsp.wav)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char *filename = "audio/M1F1-int16-AFsp.wav";
    ifstream sampleStream(filename,ios::binary);
    int nsamples = 10000;
    short * samples;
    if (sampleStream.is_open())
    {
        sampleStream.seekg(44);  // Skip all of the header. 
        samples = new short[nsamples];
        sampleStream.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(samples), sizeof(short)*nsamples);
        sampleStream.close();
    }
    short max = 0; 
    short min = 32767;
    int min_at = 0; 
    int max_at = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < nsamples; i++)
    {
        if (samples[i] > max) 
        {
            max = samples[i];
            max_at = i;
        }
        if (samples[i] < min)
        {
            min = samples[i];
            min_at = i;
        }
    }
    cout << "Max=" << max << " at " << max_at << endl;
    cout << "Min=" << min << " at " << min_at << endl;
}
```

It shows a top peak at 14325 at sample 990 [sample 495 in stereo], and a lowest level of -7125 at 8766, both of which match up when comparing to the values in the audacity software. Note that I'm relying on the x86 processor on my machine being little endian. If you are running on a Mac, then that would be the case too, unless it's a really old PowerPC Mac.

Comment: Can you please do the same with reading the SubChunk2Size from the header? It's an int at byte 40.
`sampleStream.seekg(40);`
`sampleStream.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(subChunk2Size), sizeof(int));`

Comment: Yes, as long as the machine is little-endian.